# How do I restrict users?

Tags: permissions, users

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. I would like to create a new account, for other people using my computer. I would like my guest to have access to Internet, text editor and other application installed on my computer without having access to my data (and obviously system settings).

I have added a user "guest" using graphic interface (`System -> Administration -> Users and groups`). My guest has now access to the application, but not full - wine and VirtualBox are empty (wine has only wine notepad, on VirtualBox there is no virtual machine installed). Internet and chat are fine, but "guest" has the access to anything in the computer via terminal, and I would like to keep him in his guests `home` (there are a lot of people using my computer, not all of them I know well).

I have found on http://www.ubuntu.pl/ how to change user's privileges via terminal and I'm wondering if the command `chmod -vR --preserve-root 700 /home/maria` 
is fine?

`/home` has two directories: `guest` and `maria`.

And how to ensure for my guest the access to applications installed on wine and VirtualBox without installing it once again?

This is an output for guests `groups`:

```
guest@marysia-ubuntu:~$ groups
guest adm dialout fax cdrom floppy tape dip video plugdev fuse nopasswdlogin
guest@marysia-ubuntu:~$
```

And this for marias `groups`:

```
maria@marysia-ubuntu:~$ groups
maria adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare guest
maria@marysia-ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're only worried about other users being able to see your files, run `chmod -R o-rwx /home/maria`. It revokes all permissions to the world (including guest).

`guest` does not belong to the admin group, which means he cannot run commands as other users (like root) through sudo (OK)

As noted by Takkat, anyone who has physical access to the machine could gain access to the files. The only way to protect you from that is encrypting the drive. If you put a BIOS password on the machine, the visitor can take out the HDD from it.

Comment: But anybody could read your /home when booting from a live CD or USB. Encryption only is safe.

Comment: If you really do not trust your guest, you would not leave him alone in a chamber. I guess OP wants to prevent a quick look in her Home folder.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Thanks for `chmod`. But what about wine and VirtualBox applications? Is it possible to add it to guests account?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: yes, I don't have top secret data in my computer, I just prefere to be able to leave my computer to anybody who could need it and I've seen strange peoples behavior...

Comment: Well, VirtualBox saves it's settings and machines to `~/.VirtualBox`, but do you really want to allow your guest to access those files? He could mess up your guests. It's better to create a custom VirtualBox guest for the guest account. The same goes for Wine.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: I'm not sure if I understand what you meant by `He could mess up your guests`. But the conclusion is that I should install once again, on guest account, all wine and VirtualBox applications? Or is it possible that I enable it if somebody needs using my password? It's much more important for VirtualBox

Comment: You could create a bind mount, which bypasses the permissions on `/home/maria` (`mount --bind /home/maria/.VirtualBox /home/guest/.VirtualBox`). However, you should should enable read and write on `/home/maria/.VirtualBox` and its siblings for the group "guest".

Comment: Ok, it seems a bit complicated for me for a while. Maybe with time I'll manage. Thanks a lot for your help.