# Can I restrict file access to other users?

Tags: permissions, directory, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I restrict users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28238/how-do-i-restrict-users)

I'm sharing my computer with my roommate, and she needs access to my libre office, but I don't want her to see my financial/tax information.  I've giver her a separate user account.  Is there a way to make my folder not show up or be password protected for her username?  I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with a gnome classic desktop.  I'm not worried about her going through terminal, I just want to hide those files or that folder in her session.

Comment: Welcome Scott, Why dont you create a login password and have her access ubuntu as "Guest"

Comment: Please see this similar question [How do I restrict Users?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28238/how-do-i-restrict-users)

Comment: have you tested this at all?  a real user account without sudo shouldn't be able to see inside your user's home folder

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that by changing the permissions on the file(s) so that they are not readable by "others" (sometimes called world or public).

Right-click in Nautllus, go to the Permissions tab, and uncheck all three (read, write and execute) under the Others section.

From the terminal, you can also use `chmod` to accomplish this, setting permissions to `640` for regulat files and `750` for any binaries.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I had given the other user universal access.  I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Scott, in that case please consider accepting the answer to close the question.